# Can Gazebo use color/textures from collada files?

Tags: gazebo, collada

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Electric, Gazebo would color my simulated robot parts using the colors stored in the Collada .dae files.  In Fuerte, the robot seems to be just gray, with a material script used for color.  Is there any way to force Gazebo to use the colors stored in the Collada models?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33300/can-gazebo-use-color/textures-from-collada-files?/) by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 276 on 2012-05-04

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on 2012-05-04**:
my dae's still color my models...  mind posting the model file that's having the problem?

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) on 2012-05-08**:
Perhaps the textures need to be in a certain location?  I used to keep them in the same directory as the .dae files, but I've also tried the MEdia/materials/textures/ directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, can you post your model for testing?  There's an [outstanding ticket](https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/trac/ticket/46), possibly the same problem.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0